# CSS - Animation triggers back when mouse hover

Tags: css, less

I'm working on a CSS slider animation.
Everything is pretty much done apart from one last thing:

The wanted behaviour is that if I hover over the slider thumb, the slider grows in height and the value moves in the centre of the slider. This works as expected, however when the slider thumb goes underneath the newly positioned value, it goes back to the previous size (basically reverting the animation).

I think that I need some sort of "pass-through", so that basically even if I'm not technically hovering on the slider, the value doesn't interfere at all with my animation.

I know, it is not clear at all, that's why I'm including a codepen to help you better understand what I mean. Change the slider and stop it at 29. Then try sliding again and you will see the wrong effect and what I mean.
https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/NYOoXR?editors=0110

I'm also posting the code here for future reference: (note: is done using LESScss):

```
@temp0-14: #185fb6;
@temp15-19: #00bcd4;
@temp20-23: #ffc107;
@temp24-31: #ef6b52;
@gaps: 8, 4, 4, 15;
@temps: @temp24-31, @temp20-23,@temp15-19, @temp0-14;
@darkText: #000;
@lightText: #fff;
@percentage: 20%;
@desaturate-percentage: 40%;
.gaps-loop(@i, @prevgap) when (@i > 0) {
  @gap: extract(@gaps, @i);
  @temp: extract(@temps, @i);
  .span-gen-loop(@j) when (@j < @gap) {
    @k: @j + @prevgap;
    .temp-@{k} {
      display: block;
      background: @temp;
      color: contrast(@temp, @darkText, @lightText, @percentage);
      &:hover {
        //background: darken(@temp, 8%);
      }
    }

    .temp-color-@{k} {
      color: contrast(@temp, @darkText, @lightText, @percentage);
    }

    .span-gen-loop(@j + 1);
  }
  .span-gen-loop(0);
  .gaps-loop(@i - 1, @prevgap + @gap);
}
.gaps-loop(length(@gaps), 0);
.animate-color-change {
  transition: background 0.8s ease;
}

/* Slider custom style */
@entryHeight: 60px;
@sliderTrackHeight: 25px;
@sliderThumbHeight: @sliderTrackHeight;
@sliderThumbWidth: 25px;

.entry-external-container {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: @entryHeight;
  min-height: @entryHeight;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  .dataName {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    padding-left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: dataNameIn 0.4s forwards;
  }
  .dataValue {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: right;
    right: 10px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation: dataValueZoomOut 0.1s forwards;
  }
  .slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    .custom-slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: @sliderTrackHeight;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      margin: 0;
      animation: sliderAnimationBackgroundOut 0.3s;
      &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: @sliderThumbWidth;
        height: @sliderThumbHeight;
        background: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: height 0.25s, box-shadow 0.4s;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
      &:hover,
      &:active {
        &~.dataName {
          animation: dataNameOut 0.4s forwards;
        }
        &~.dataValue {
          animation: dataValueZoomIn 0.4s forwards;
          &:hover{pointer-events:none;}
        }
        animation: sliderAnimationBackgroundIn 0.3s forwards;
        &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0;
          height: @entryHeight;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          border-left: none;
          -webkit-box-shadow: -7px 0px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          -moz-box-shadow: -7px 0px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: -7px 0px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          background: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            -20 0,
            100% 0,
            from(transparent),
            to(white),
            color-stop(80%, white)
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes sliderAnimationBackgroundIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: @sliderTrackHeight;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: @entryHeight;
  }
}
@keyframes sliderAnimationBackgroundOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: @entryHeight;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: @sliderTrackHeight;
  }
}


@keyframes dataNameOut {
    0% {opacity: 1;top: 0}
    20% {opacity: 0;top: -15px}
    100% {top: -40px;opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes dataNameIn {
    0% {top: -40px;opacity: 0}  
    20% {opacity: 0;top: -15px}
    100% {opacity: 1;top: 0}

}

@keyframes dataValueZoomIn {
      0% { transform: scale(1); top: 5px; right: 7.5px;}
      25% { transform: scale(1.2);  top: 10px; right: 10px;}
      50% { transform: scale(1.3);  top: 15px;right: 11px;}
      75% { transform: scale(1.4);  top: 20px;right: 13px;}
      100% { transform: scale(1.5);top: 20px;right: 13.7px;}
}
@keyframes dataValueZoomOut {
      100% { transform: scale(1); top: 5px; right: 7.5px;}
      75% { transform: scale(1.2);  top: 10px; right: 10px;}
      50% { transform: scale(1.3);  top: 15px;right: 11px;}
      25% { transform: scale(1.4);  top: 20px;right: 13px;}
      0% { transform: scale(1.5);top: 20px;right: 13.7px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to prevent an element from being hovered :

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse
>   events.

```
.dataValue { 
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxzoxm)

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. Can you try it on the pen provided please? thanks

Comment: Thanks that actually works. I did try it but it was in a wrong way (check line 113 to see how i was trying to use it if interested). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same effect setting the hover state to the parent.

[PEN](https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/PRyVvz?editors=0110)

```
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    &:hover {
      .custom-slider {
       ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Note: Is not a good practice to nest more than 3 levels deep,